# Пути для CSS Bootstrap

Tags: java, bootstrap, jsp

Скачал Bootstrap чтобы привязать его к JSP страницам, JSP страницы лежат в каталоге `webapp/jsp` , CSS лежит в `webapp/css`, страница упорно отказывается видеть файл CSS, хотя по логике путь правильный:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: может где то настраивается путь по умолчанию отдельно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, сложите все статические ресурсы в одно место - каталог resource или static. Во-вторых, не обязательно, но желательно явно указать в web.xml, что содержимое этого каталога обрабатывается сервлетом по умолчанию:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

В-третьих, в самом jsp файле лучше использовать абсолютный путь:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
    <head>
        ...

        <c:set var="staticRoot" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static"/>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${staticRoot}/css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="${staticRoot}/js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Наконец, ещё проще и лучше подключать bootstrap из CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо исользовал 3 вариант