# Не подключается bundle.js в Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

У меня следующая структура:

src

-- main

---- webapp

------ resources

-------- build

---------- bundle.js

------ WEB-INF (там файлы jsp)

В jsp подключаю его следующим путем:

http://localhost:8080/webapp/resources/build/bundle.js

Ошибки подключения нет, но он не отрабатывает. При этом если выложить скрипт на хостинг и заменить путь на тот, где он там находится, - он будет работать. Как это поправить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Пути для CSS Bootstrap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645417/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-css-bootstrap)

Comment: Сделал по тому, что написано в ответе, но у меня возникла следующая ошибка: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/main/main/resources/build/bundle.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringMVC'. С ней я же сталкивался, поэтому и заменил путь на `http://localhost:8080/webapp/resources/build/bundle.js`.

Comment: Почему-то вариант с {pageContext.request.contextPath} не сработал. Сработал 1 вариант: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page